# What is the correct way to turn a second computer into a simple expansion for the first?

Tags: networking, usb, resources, distributed-computing

I have two computers side-by side in the same large case.   One is a gaming rig, one is currently just managing case fans and doesn't even have an OS.

I have a truly insane number of peripherals.   The case, of course, had some bad front panel ports because those front panel headers are usually hot garbage anyway.  Between USB expansion cards to get around the problem and other equipment in the case, my PCI-E slots are full.  I have an HTC Vive, however, and need to open a PCI-E slot on the mainboard in order to install the new wireless adapter's PCI-E receiver.

What I would like to do is make the older computer that is just managing fans into a slave unit to the primary machine in the case.  I know I can do this over LAN, but part of my goal is to *not* put the second machine out there for any other computer or device on the network to see.  I want to guarantee exclusive use of all resources on the "slave" machine for the "master" machine.  I also want to do this at no less than 480Mbps, so that I see very little to no latency on connected USB devices.  I would like the "slave" to only run Linux, Win7, or even XP in a pinch but with an NTFS file system I can make use of from the "master" Windows 10 machine.  Finally, once the initial setup is complete, I'd like to run the "slave" with no monitor, keyboard, or mouse and manage it only from the "master" or bios in emergencies.  What is the best way to approach this, and what equipment do I need?

Answer (score 1):

Connect the old and new computers via LAN (ethernet), directly, with a cable inside the case. If the new computer should get connected to LAN, use a second LAN adapter. That will take care of the private communication.

Using the "old" computer without monitor, keyboard, mouse is easy under Linux: Just configure it for no console/graphics, allow remote login etc. There are plenty of embedded systems using Linux that work this way. There'll still be a lot of details to take care of before you can use it as "slave", though.

However, using the BIOS without a monitor and keyboard will be hard - PC BIOS are not built for that.

If you are adventurous, you can try to replace the BIOS with an Open-Source BIOS and customize it to your needs, but this is going to be *very* difficult, and next to impossible if your "old" hardware needs special initialization.

If you are in luck, your BIOS will boot properly without monitor and keyboard, and you'll only have to reconnect monitor and keyboard in the rare case where you'll have to change anything.